# How do I start a workflow from a timer job?

Tags: workflow, timer-jobs

I need to start a particular workflow in a list from a timer job. Is there any sample code for starting the workflow in the timer job's `Execute()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
public override void Execute (Guid targetInstanceId)
{
    SPWorkflowManager workflowManager = 
        this.WebApplication.Sites["GUID"].WorkflowManager;
    SPWorkflowAssociationCollection workflowAssociationCollection = 
        this.WebApplication.Sites["GUID"].RootWeb.Lists["ID"].WorkflowAssociations;

    foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation workflowAssociation in workflowAssociationCollection)
    {
        if (String.Compare(
                workflowAssociation.BaseId.ToString("B"), {"Workflow GUID"}, true) == 0)
        {
            workflowManager.StartWorkflow("GETYOUR ITEM OR LIST OBJECT",
                        workflowAssociation, workflowAssociation.AssociationData, true); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thank you for this !! However have some questions, In the timer job I have conditions like if the list expiry date is greater than today, I need to send the reminder letter for the group member. Now which type of workflow i need to create? The GUID you mentioned, where I will get? Plz contact me on reenuiss@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

Refer my [blogpost](http://syspsutha.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/timer-job-to-start-workflow-in-list.html) on this. I have provided sample code.

Comment: Please don't just add a link. Add the actual content since a link may break in the future. Thx